File Exists error when trying to increase the upload size limit of Wordpress Docker
So I have a Wordpress running on Docker and the upload size is 2M which is very low.
Based on this answer on Github and all the answers here my compose.yaml file is as below:
services:

  mysql:

    image: mysql:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql

  wordpress:
  
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      - wp_data:/var/www/html

volumes:
  mysql_data:
  wp_data:

Docker pulls the images and starts the containers and then gives me this error:
Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/run/desktop/mnt/host/d/Projects/Wordpress/artanetwork.com/uploads.ini': mkdir /run/desktop/mnt/host/d: file exists

If I remove mounting uploads.ini file, everything works fine.
I have no idea how to fix this.
This is Docker v26.1.4 on Windows 11.
